# named path not working in react-router-dom react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I am using `react-router-dom` for routing purposes. This is my code:

```js
//Libraries
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-tabify';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';

//Components
import HomePage from './containers/HomePage';
import PersonsPage from './containers/PersonsPage';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
      <Route exact path="/:id" component={PersonsPage}/>

      // here i want to use like this --> <Route exact path="/personPage/:id" component={PersonsPage}/>


    </div>
  </Router>
)
export default withRouter(connect()(App));
```

`Route exact path="/:id" component={PersonsPage}/>` this works , but this `Route exact path="/personPage/:id" component={PersonsPage}/>` this didn't works for me .  Can someone clarify/help me from this pls

Comment: It may not work if you are having you Link component path like `/12`. can you show how are you routing

Comment: Instead of using Link , i'm passing the data from my app url manually(for some reasons) .

Comment: What is the order of your routes? did you try putting route with `path="/personPage/:id"` before  route with `path="/:id"`?

Comment: no need of order here i think . i want to know how to use name instead of that empt route . Ex: instead of this <path="/:id"> , i want  <path="/personPage/:id"> this

Comment: because i have only 2 routing , 1. default home ("/") and 2. Person page (/personpage:id)

Comment: When you do path="/personPage/:id" do you get any error in console? or you just see a blank page ?

Comment: my errors are like  this: GET http://localhost:3060/xx/css/bundle.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply wrap your routers in [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md) component. But remember to put `<Route exact path="/:id" component={PersonsPage}/>` as last entry.

Here you have an example in one file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';

const HomePage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>HomePage</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/user/Tom">Tom</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/user/John">John</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/user/Andy">Andy</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const PersonsPage = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Profile: {props.match.params.name}</h1>
  </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
        <Route exact path="/user/:name" component={PersonsPage}/>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);

render(
  <Router>
    <AppWithRouter />
  </Router>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here you have link to working version https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqpraz

Comment: @Beckham_Vinoth - I edited my answer. Please check now.

Comment: tnx a lot for your effort bro :) , but i need like this --> <Route exact path="/PersonsPage/:id" component={PersonsPage}/>

Comment: the path should have some name --> /someName/:parameterData

Comment: I added prefix "/user/" to url and it also works. Please check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqpraz

Comment: It is working nice in `stackblitz` . Let me implement this in my code and update you here :)

Comment: Everything works good in ` stackblitz ` but it is showing error in App alone , it is related to some bundle.js  issues i think . will add a separate question for that